# Unable to install packages in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am getting `Connection Failed` on the following packages on 14.04

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed
```

How can i make sure (find) the new location of these Packages?

Answer (score 0):

The repos in your sources list still look to be active

- [Fish Shell Repo](https://launchpad.net/~fish-shell/+archive/ubuntu/release-2)
- [Ondrej Repo](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

It may be that those particular paths to the translations may be broken - have you looked at your sources list in /etc/apt/sources.list?

It might be worth removing these sources and re-adding the sources.

Comment: tried that, but no luck, not sure why this is happening.